# Javascript Wordpress field validation match

Tags: javascript, wordpress, validation

Can someone help with this. Ive been stuck for a while now.

I need some java script that can match two fields in a contact form to make sure they are the same.
Example: Phone Number and Phone Number Again. Two fields must match.

Im using fast secure contact form in WP and placing this in the field for the needed JS but cant get the code im using to work.

fields are currently named the following:

> Need field3_4 to match field3_5
>  field3_4 is called phone
>
> ### > field3_4 is called phone again

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function validateMe()
    {
    var phone = document.getElementById('field3_4').value;
    var phone_again = document.getElementById('field3_5').value;
    if(phone!=phone_again)
    {
    alert("Numbers are not same in both fields");
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Yeah they match correctly!!");
    }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Please show us your code so far.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Here is a sample code
<script type="text/javascript">
    function isNumber(evt) {
        evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
        if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    function validateMe()
    {
    var number1 = document.getElementById('number1').value;
    var number2 = document.getElementById('number2').value;
    if(number1!=number2)
    {
    alert("Numbers are not same in both fields");
    return false;
    }
    else
    {
    alert("Yeah they match correctly!!");
    }
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form name="myform" id="myform">

    <table width="100%" border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>Number1</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="number1" id="number1" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" /></td>
      </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>Number2</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="number2" id="number2" onkeypress="return isNumber(event);" /></td>
      </tr>    
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateMe();" /></td>
      </tr>
    </table>

    </form>
```

Comment: Thanks, but im not fully understanding.

Comment: This is what I have so far and it doesnt work. Ths is new to me.

Comment: <script>



var fieldalias="phone_again"

function verify(phone, phone_again){
var passed=false
if (phone.value==''){
alert("Please fill out the "+fieldalias+"!")
phone.focus()
}
else if (phone_again.value==''){
alert("Please verify the "+fieldalias+"!")
phone_again.focus()
}
else if (phone.value!=phone_again.value){
alert("The two "+fieldalias+"s do not match")
phone.select()
}
else
passed=true

return passed

}

</script>

<form name=FSContact3 onSubmit="return verify(this.phone, this.phone_again)">

Comment: Thank you for the sample. I edit, but I think wrong as I cant get it to work.

Comment: I cant use the editor box here as it says I need to wait and the code was to long for comment section. ARGH

Comment: I added the edited code to the original post. sorry for confusion